# Rails rake db:schema:load fails with new database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I ran rake db:drop (successfully) and ran rake db:create (successfully) but rake db:schema:load is throwing a strange error that I can't figure out.

```
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted! PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "admins" does not exist
LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                                      ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                    pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"admins"'::regclass
                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't totally understand why, but **rake db:schema:load** was having problems with one of my FactoryGirl files.  I temporarily deleted file and **rake db:schema:load** worked fine.

The problem was caused by an incorrectly defined FactoryGirl association.  Still not sure why factory girl initialized during rake db:schema:load.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using FactoryBot (FactoryGirl) and your factory contains any model type references, make sure they are enclosed in curly braces.  That prevents `db:schema:load` from blowing up and you don't have to comment out your factory.

For example, let's say you have a Car model with wheels and an engine, and you have 2 types of engines in your seed data and are using traits to specify the engine type.

This code will blow up `db:schema:load`:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :car do
    wheels

    trait(:v8) {
      engine Engine.find_by_type('V8') 
    }

    trait(:i4) {
      engine Engine.find_by_type('I4') 
    }
  end
end
```

This will prevent `db:schema:load` from blowing up:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :car do
    wheels

    trait(:v8) {
      engine { Engine.find_by_type('V8') }
    }

    trait(:i4) {
      engine { Engine.find_by_type('I4') }
    }
  end
end
```

Here is a discussion about it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/issues/134

UPDATE:  This can happen when specifying the class for the factory as well:

This code will blow up `db:schema:load`:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hot_rod, class: Car do
```

This will prevent `db:schema:load` from blowing up (uses symbol instead of model type):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hot_rod, class: :car do
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with this on a project I inherited. It was to do with routing constraints that were loading models from the database e.g.

```
constraints(foobar: /#{FooBar.pluck(:name).join('|')}|other/) do
```

To get started quickly I just commented the block, ran the `rake` task then uncommented the block and everything was golden. Obviously not the issue of the original question, but a fix for the same error with slightly different problem due to loading problems.

Answer (score 1):

I often facing the same issues. Have you ever ever to manage your database **manually before**? I mean, let say you have done creating migration and so on so far, then you drop table manually. Please check your migration file, its overlapping somehow each other.

Try to located the **migration file** that make this stack. And try to **edit** it, more even **delete** it if needed.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.